# Store 2 inputs having same name into 1 'address' column of the database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two address inputs `'address1'` and `'address2'` having the same name as 'address[]' . I want to put the value of both the inputs in a single address column of the database but the problem is that data of only 2nd input is being stored into the database.

```
index.php
```

```css
  $addressData = $_POST['address']; 
    foreach ($addressData as  $addressValue) {
              $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`name` ,`address` , `birthdate` ,`age` , `coach` , `phone`,`email` ,`password`)
             VALUES ( '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name'])."' ,  '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $addressValue)."' ,'".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['birthdate'])."' ,'".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['age'])."' , '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['coach'])."' , '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['phone'])."' , '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."' , '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password'])."')";
                                 }
```

```html
 <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Address1</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" id="address" class="form-control" name="address[]" placeholder="Home address">
      <span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Address2</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" id="address2" class="form-control" name="address[]" placeholder="City,Pincode....">
      <span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: In your foreach loop, the second iteration will overwrite the first, hence, only the second value will be inserted into the database.  I usually have separate columns for each address line.

Comment: @ymas Makes a good point. Assume your 2 address's are `10 The high Street` and `SomeTown`. When you concatenate the 2 lines into one column, what happens when you later want to know everyone that lives in `SomeTown`... You turn a simple query into a nightmare query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you do insert inside the foreach loop. If you want the address to be saved on a single table, you might want to combine the address first and do insert outside the foreach loop. See the updated code below

```
$addressData = $_POST['address']; 

$address = "";
foreach ($addressData as  $addressValue) {
    $address .= "\n" . $addressValue;
}               
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`name` ,`address` , `birthdate` ,`age` , `coach` , `phone`,`email` ,`password`)

           VALUES ( '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name'])."' ,
                    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $address)."' ,
                    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['birthdate'])."' ,
                    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['age'])."' ,
                    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['coach'])."' ,
                    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['phone'])."' ,
                    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."' ,
                    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password'])."'   )";
```

Comment: Note for OP: you could alternatively consider using "implode" rather than foreach for the $addressData.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php  I would recommend you take a second look at your schema.

Comment: No problem :) Might as well accept the answer if it helps you and also as ymas suggested try using implode.

Comment: @ymas thank for you advice..will make necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

The name attribute specifies the name of an  element.

The name attribute is used to reference elements in a JavaScript, or to reference form data after a form is submitted.

You should not have the same name for 2 elements.

Why just not call it Adress1 and Adress2

Answer (score 0):

For storing multiple values in a single column, create a new table that stores address, and link it to the main table.

```
users(pid, address)
address(fkid, address)
```

From the sample, link the 2 tables by referencing fkid as a foreign key of the address to the primary key of the table. In these way, you can store multiple the same datas in a particular ID.

So taken from my sample, to insert it after your the insertion of the user table, get the created id by:

```
$last_insert_id = mysqli_insert_id();
```

Then, insert the addresses:

```
foreach($addressData as $addressValue) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO user(id, address) VALUE($last_insert_id, $addressValue);
}
```

It is useful, like 1 user having multiple email accounts, or multiple groups that joins. And can be use in a bunch of ways, rather than storing it as a text separated with commas.